# VS Code Import Error Cannot Import Name, How to Fix Without Restarting?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Since yesterday I've started getting an error when importing objects from my own created py files in VS Code using Python.

I'm creating a multi page dashboard using Plotly and I have each page as a separate py file, as well as separate py files to import data and to hold functions.

Only newly imported functions, dataframes or variables are affected from within that VS Code session, so if I save my code and restart VS Code then the import works fine. As soon as I decide to import a newly created function then I have to restart my session again.

My settings.json looks like the following:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "emmet.preferences": {
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-d",
        "Ubuntu-20.04"
    ],
    "launch": {


        "configurations": [
            //{"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}}
        ],
        "compounds": []
    },

}
```

I've tried using `{"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}}` but that didn't work and I can't find anyone else who's having this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: setting `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` or `python.analysis.extraPaths`

Comment: Set them to the file path of where my project is located? Won't I then need to change this setting every time I work on a different project?

Comment: you change that setting in the workspace settings: `.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: so I've added the following: 

``` "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "D:\\Spira_Analytics\\304_Clothing\\GA_Dashboard\\"
    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "D:\\Spira_Analytics\\304_Clothing\\GA_Dashboard\\"
    ]
``` 
but I'm still getting the error ```ImportError: cannot import name...```

Comment: `ImportError` is an error from the python interpreter not from VSC, change `PYTHONPATH`